# Python script in desktop app requires non-compromisable password to decode encrypted ZIP file from server

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I have a Python script running in a desktop app, which has an embedded Python 2.7 interpreter. The script is running on either a Windows, Linux or MacOS system.

The script needs to access a remote server ZIP file to do its work. The ZIP file is encrypted with a password.

Currently the script uses a plain text password in the *.py file:

```
# get password from some place (UI) and use password **without** enabling compromise, how?
zip_password = "27c1b54b83cd24a0c30771d6bdc35315"  # just an example PW
importer = ZipImporter(file_names, "http://" + host_name + "/some-path/protected.zip", zip_password))
```

I'm obviously not an expert in this field, but I see, that providing the password in code is a no-go, compiled code or not.

**QUESTION/S:**

How do I get the password over the net to the end user from some centralized instance (me) without being compromisable?

In any case, returning the password from some Python code in the script won't really work. Or does it?

What are the alternatives here?

Comment: Why not confirm the identity of the client, then securely (TLS) send the content of the file to the client, after unlocking the ZIP with the password at the server end?

Comment: It currently has practical limitations. The embedded Python 2.7 interpreter isn't compiled with HTTPS. It's a big problem generally. I can't even download the ZIP file securely at the moment, so I have to maximize every remaining security aspect while being stuck on HTTP.

Comment: Include your comment in your question.